# Empty picklist value is getting saved as null

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, test-setup

I am trying test a piece of code by changing a Status__c field on Save_Attempt__c Object. I am explicitly setting the value of Status picklist to an empty string and not null but when I query, it's coming out as null.

Here's the code:

```
Save_Attempts__c aSaveAttempt = new Save_Attempts__c();
aSaveAttempt.Status__c = 'In Progress';
insert aSaveAttempt;

Save_Attempts__c parentResult = [SELECT Id, Status__c from 
Save_Attempts__c where Id = :aSaveAttempt.Id];

System.debug('parentResult.Status__c: '+parentResult.Status__c);
// Above line getting printed as "parentResult.Status__c: In Progress"

aSaveAttempt.Status__c = '';
update aSaveAttempt;

parentResult = [SELECT Id, Status__c from Save_Attempts__c where Id = 
:aSaveAttempt.Id];

System.debug('parentResult.Status__c: '+parentResult.Status__c);
// Above line getting printed as "aSaveAttempt.Status__c: null"
```

The Status__c field has "Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set" checkbox unchecked.

am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apex [primitive type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm) underlying Picklist fields is a String, which has a unique property derived from the underlying data storage:

> Empty Strings and Trailing Whitespace: sObject String field values follow the same rules as in the SOAP API: *they can never be empty (only null)*, and they can never include leading and trailing whitespace. These conventions are necessary for database storage.
>
> Conversely, Strings in Apex can be null or empty and can include leading and trailing whitespace, which can be used to construct a message.

(Emphasis is mine). So you cannot in a field whose underlying data storage is a String store a literal empty string value; it's stored as a `null`.

As a further illustration, if you perform a describe of a picklist field, using Workbench for example, you find on a picklist field these properties:

> soapType: xsd:string
> type: picklist

Just showing that those types under the hood are the same.